# is there any cell number limitation when GridView.AutoGenerateColumns false?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, gmgridviewcell

I have a problem when I am generating a `GridView` column manually.
my program stops at this line:

```
e.Row.Cells[42].Text = "x";
```

and throws the below error:

> "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter
>   name: index    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified
>   argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index"

My HTML code is:

```
<div class="scrolling-container">
    <br/>

    <asp:GridView EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="true" ID="StationGridView" runat="server"
        GridLines="None" CellSpacing="1" AlternatingRowStyle-Wrap="false"
        Font-Names="tahoma" Font-Size="14px" CellPadding="3"
        AllowSorting="True"
        ViewStateMode="Disabled" EnableViewState="false"
        AllowPaging="True" PageSize="15" dir="rtl" Width="100%"
        OnRowDataBound="StationGridView_RowDataBound">

        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#d7effd" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Navy" Font-Size="12px" Font-Underline="false" />

        <FooterStyle BackColor="#d7effd" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Navy"
            VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Size="16px" />

        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#c0c0c0" ForeColor="#000000" Height="25px" />

    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

My source code is :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    //Load data

        PortalDataSetTableAdapters.VW_StationTableAdapter stationsAdapter = new PortalDataSetTableAdapters.VW_StationTableAdapter();
        PortalDataSet.VW_StationDataTable Station;
        Station = stationsAdapter.GetData();


        StationGridView.DataSource = Station;
        StationGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

         StationGridView.DataBind();
    }
}


protected void StationGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{                  
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        { 
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "a";
            e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "b";
            e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "c";
            .
            .
            e.Row.Cells[42].Text = "x";
            e.Row.Cells[43].Text = "x";
            e.Row.Cells[44].Text = "x";
         }
}
```

When the number of cells are generating goes more than 42 (exactly on the line `e.Row.Cells[42].Text = "x";`), the error happens. Why does this occur?

Comment: Because you only have 42  cells in that row (41 + the 0th row, makes 42)? Why do you think you have more than 42 cells in that row?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have billion of rows, columns count is not the problem here
(source: http://forums.asp.net/post/3380845.aspx )

You certainly have only 42 columns, and when you're trying to reach the 43th, you get the ArugmentOutOfRangeException.

Comment: my query has about more than 1000 record but when I fetch the number of records for my grid view it is 42, I don't know why?. even when I execute my query in my model(mydataset.xsd file in app_code folder) it returns complete data,

Comment: So now your problem is the number of rows ? (a record = a row ?)

I don't know how to help you, sorry